# why the kernel size become greater while the spatial size of feature map goes down in inception network？

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, classification, conv-neural-network

In the inception networks like inception-v3 and inception-v4, the kernel sizes are smaller in the lower layers,such as 3*3, but in the higher layers, the kernel sizes seem to be larger,such as 5*5,7*7,although they may be factorized to n*1&1*n later.But as network goes deeper,the spatial size of the feature map goes down,is there any relationship between these two thing?

ps:My question is why the kernel sizes in the lower layers seem to be samller(no more than 3*3),and you can find larger kernel size like 7*7 in the higher layers(more precisely, in the middle layers ).Is there any relationship between the spatial size of the feature map and the spatial spatial size of the conv kernels?Take inception v3 as a example, when the spatial sizes of the feature maps are larger than 35 in the first few layers of the network,the biggest kernel size is 5*5, but when the spatial size become 17, kernel size like 7*7 is used.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Generally as you go deep into the network:-

1. The spatial size of feature map decreases to localize the object and
   to reduce the computational cost.
2. The number of filters/kernels
       increase as usually the initial layer represent generic features,
       while the deeper layer represents more detailed features.  Since
       initial layers learn only primitive regularities in the data, you do
       not need to have high volumes of filter there. However as you go
       deep, you should try to look into as much details as possible, hence
       increase in the number of filters/kernels. Therefore increasing the
       number of filters in deeper layers increases the representational
       power of the network.

In inception module, at each layer, kernels of multiple size (1x1, 3x3, 5x5) are used in computation and and resulting feature map is concatenated and passed to the next layer.

Comment: What i mean is why the kernel sizes in the low layers seem to be samller(no more than 3*3),and you can find larger kernel size like 7*7 in the higher layers(or more precisely, in the middle layers ).Take inception v3 as a example, when the spatial size is larger than 35,the biggest kernel size is 5*5, but when  the spatial size become 17, kernel size like 7*7 is used.